# Why cant i access variable in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why I can't access the value of variable ("dial") any help would be great.

```html
<input type="text" class="dial" value="50" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
                    var dial = $(".dial");
                    
                    function onDialChange(){
                        console.log(dial.value); // for some probably obvious reason I can't access this value.
                    }
                    
                    dial.knob({
                        'release':function(){},
                        'change':onDialChange,
                        'draw':function(){},
                    });
                                 

                });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your code in a script tag?

Comment: `value` is a property of DOM element, not jquery object. You have to use `.val()` method instead

Comment: yes it is updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` is the proper function in jquery to return value of input element.

```
console.log(dial.val());
```

For your [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 3):

```
function onDialChange(){
    console.log(dial.val()); //for value
    console.log(dial.text());  //for text
}
```